# DOCKER_HOST in Azure pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I have a locally hosted Azure DevOps server running on Windows 10. Because we want to avoid Docker Desktop (because $$$), I'm running the Linux version of `dockerd` under WSL. Using the Windows docker client from the command line works fine:

```sh
docker.exe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx run --rm hello-world
```

But I can't get docker to work in an Azure pipeline. I keep getting this error:

```
Starting: Initialize containers
C:\Windows\docker.EXE version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}'
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
'
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\docker.EXE', arguments 'version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}''.
Finishing: Initialize containers
```

I know `dockerd` is running because I can talk to it if I run `docker.exe` by hand. I've checked to make sure Azure is running the same `docker.exe` executable as I am. It looks as though Azure isn't using the `-H` option for some reason. Here's the relevant part of my `azure_pipelines.yml`:

```yaml
pool:
  name: Default
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

container:
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  env:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2375
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration? Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: um thats not defeating the license...

Comment: What do you mean?